# Vagrant install of CloudFoundry on AWS: Provider expected: aws Provider of box: virtualbox

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, cloud-foundry

I am having an issue with the following guide: http://www.activestate.com/blog/2013/07/how-deploy-cloud-foundry-v2-aws-vagrant in installing CloudFoundry on AWS using Vagrant.

I have followed it down to the point where I have to deploy using the command: vagrant up --provider=aws

This prints the following output which I have had little luck debugging due to my lack of understanding of Vagrant:

Bringing machine 'cf-install' up with 'aws' provider...
[cf-install] Box 'precise64' was not found. Fetching box from specified URL for
the provider 'aws'. Note that if the URL does not have
a box for this provider, you should interrupt Vagrant now and add
the box yourself. Otherwise Vagrant will attempt to download the
full box prior to discovering this error.
Downloading or copying the box...
Extracting box...te: 49.7M/s, Estimated time remaining: 0:00:01)
An error occurred while executing multiple actions in parallel.
Any errors that occurred are shown below.

An error occurred while executing the action on the 'cf-install'
machine. Please handle this error then try again:
The box you attempted to add doesn't match the provider you specified.

Provider expected: aws
Provider of box: virtualbox

One thing I noticed is my Vagrantfile has aws provider configured as such:

```
config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|

override.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

aws.access_key_id = "*****"
aws.secret_access_key = "****"
aws.keypair_name = "****"
aws.ami = "ami-23d9a94a"
aws.instance_type = "m1.large"
aws.region = "us-east-1"
aws.security_groups = ["open"]
aws.user_data = File.read('ec2-setup.sh')
override.ssh.username = "vagrant"
override.ssh.private_key_path = "******"
end
```

Which is using the same image (precise64.box) as Virtual box (seen below)

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v, override|
override.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"
v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 2 * 1024]
v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2"]
end
```

Has anyone experienced this error before or have any idea what could be causing it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

`vagrant box add dummy https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box`

Comment: The dummy.box specified here + the `ami` in the config will give you the actual base vm that you start with.